# How to embed chapters and metadata on the embedding YT-DLP script?

Tags: python, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

How to add chapters and metadata to video using the embedding script?

Thank you for your answer.

```py
import yt_dlp

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestvideo[height<=720][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[height<=720][ext=mp4]',
    'postprocessors': [ 
        {'key': 'FFmpegVideoConvertor', 'preferedformat': 'mp4'},
        {'key': 'EmbedThumbnail'},
        {'key': 'EmbedChapters'},
        {'key': 'EmbedMetadata'},
    ],
}
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(url)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chapters should be added by default if you embed metadata (see [`embed-metadata`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#post-processing-options)), your test video doesn't seem to have any though. In order to `EmbedThumbnail` you should write it to disk first with `writethumbnail`:

```
import yt_dlp

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestvideo[height<=720][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[height<=720][ext=mp4]',
    'postprocessors': [ 
        {'key': 'FFmpegVideoConvertor', 'preferedformat': 'mp4'},
        {'key': 'FFmpegMetadata'},
        {'key': 'EmbedThumbnail'}
    ],
    'writethumbnail': True
}
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(url)
```